# show following is sigma algebra generated

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

let X be a set. $\mathcal{M}_0, \mathcal{M}_1 \subset 2^X$ which are defined as follows .

1. $A \in \mathcal{M}_{0} \leftrightarrow  A $ is finite or $A^{c}$ is finite
2. $A \in \mathcal{M}_{1} \leftrightarrow  A $ is countable or $A^{c}$ is countable

> prove that $\mathcal{M}_1$ is sigma algebra generated by $\mathcal{M}_0$

$\mathcal{M}_1$ is already sigma algebra and $\mathcal{M}_{0} \subset \mathcal{M}_1$. Now I just have to show that if $\mathcal{M}'$ is any sigma algebra s.t $\mathcal{M}_0 \subset \mathcal{M}'$ then $\mathcal{M}_1 \subset \mathcal{M}' $ which is to say that if $A$ is countable or $A^{c}$ is countable then $A \in \mathcal{M}'$.

1)Let $A$ is countable then we have that $\displaystyle A = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} \{a_i\}$ , now $\{a_i\}$'s belong to $\mathcal{M}_0$ , hence they belong to $\mathcal{M}'$  and since $\mathcal{M}'$ is $\sigma$ algebra then we have that $A \in \mathcal{M}'.$

2)Let $A^{c}$ is countable then we have that $A^{c} \in \mathcal{M}'$ and since $\mathcal{M}'$ is sigma algebra we have that $A \in \mathcal{M}'$

Is there any thing wrong with above argument?